# OpenVPN: How to redirect traffic for just one client?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, redirection

I have an OpenVPN server configured on my Tomato router and I have the **Direct clients to redirect Internet traffic** option disabled because *by default* I don't want my traffic to be redirect through my home Internet connection.

But in some situations - like free wireless hotspots - I'd like all my traffic to be redirected. Can I configure a **specific client .ovpn fil**e to redirect all my traffic and another which doesn't redirect? Or is this a configuration completely server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the following directive to the client config file:

```
redirect-gateway def1
```

And optional specify dns servers:

```
dhcp-option DNS <IP>
```

But if the router uses NAT, it has to be configured to also NAT the vpn subnet. This is a server side only configuration.